# Haproxy acl - service unavailable

Tags: redirect, proxy, haproxy

I'm trying to setup haproxy acl, and it gives me `503: Service unavailable` error, even redirect by port works fine. What am I doing wrong?
Appreciate any help.

This doesn't work by `x.x.x.x/havana` :

```
   frontend https
            bind *:80
            mode http
            option httpclose
            acl otter-path path -i /havana/
            use_backend otter-server if otter-path
```

This shows backend fine `by x.x.x.x:82` :

```
 frontend otter-server
            bind *:82
            option forwardfor
            default_backend otter-server
```

Backend configuration:

```
backend otter-server
        server otter2 192.168.0.15:8004
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was - it redirects not to `backend`, but to `backend/havana`, which doesn't exist.

Solution is to remove subpath after redirect, so it points exact to backend root

```
backend annotrack-mouse
        balance roundrobin
        http-request set-uri %[url,regsub(^/havana/mouse,/,)] if { path_beg /ha$
        server annotrack-mouse 192.168.0.10:3000
        option httpchk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
acl otter-path path -i /havana/
```

remove the last "/" i.e:

```
acl otter-path path -i /havana
```

your trying to hit`x.x.x.x/havana` but matching `x.x.x.x/havana/`